# Using @html.label in list a of classes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**I am Trying to do the follow :**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Administrator";
}
@model List<MyProject.DAL.MyClass>
  @foreach (var m in Model)
         {
               @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Id)
         }
```

**MyClass :**

```
namespace MyProject.DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I make a @Html.LabelFor to work in this case (list of MyClass)? 
if the model is just a class  `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Id)` this will works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
@model List<MyProject.DAL.MyClass>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => item.Id)
}
```

Comment: Where is the difference ?

Comment: different variable names(`m` for the lamda expression, `item`  for the item in the foreach loop